# Is $f :\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R},\ f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)):=(x_1,y_1)$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, set-theory

Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$ with the topology that has a basis consisting of open intervals, and equip $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ with the product topologies. Define then the map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ by

$$\tag{1}
f((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2):=(x_1,y_1)
$$
I want to determine if this function is continuous.If I understand the definition of continuity correctly, then $f$ is continuous if

$$\tag{2}
\forall \alpha\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2 \forall U\in\mathfrak{U}(f(\alpha)) :f^{-1}(U)\in\mathfrak{U}(\alpha)
$$

where $\mathfrak{U}(\alpha)$ denotes the set of all neighborhoods of $\alpha$ (and similar for $f(\alpha)$). Pick an arbitrary $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2$ and an arbitrary $U=(a,b)\times (c,d)\in\mathfrak{U}(f(\alpha))$. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
f^{-1}(U) &=\left\{\beta \in \mathbb{R}^{2} \times \mathbb{R}^{2} \mid h(\beta) \in (a,b)\times(c,d)\right\} \\
&=\left\{\left(x_{1}, x_{2}\right),\left(y_{1}, y_{2}\right) \mid x_{1}\in (a,b), y_{1} \in (c,d) \text{ and }x_{2}, y_{2} \in \mathbb{R} \right\}\\
&=\bigcup_{x_1\in (a,b)}\bigcup_{y_1\in (c,d)}\bigcup_{x_2,y_2\in\mathbb{R}}(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\\
&=(a,b)\times\mathbb{R}\times(c,d)\times\mathbb{R}
\end{aligned}
$$

I may be making mistakes in the last lines of the last equation - please correct me if I do. If it is correct so far, how do I determine that this is indeed a neighborhood of $\alpha$?

Comment: Are you allowed to use sequential definition of continuity?

Comment: Probably a typo, but the codomain of your function in the title differs from that in the question body.

Comment: @SammyBlack, oops, corrected.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, If the mathematics is not too complex (i.e., if I can learn and understand it despite being new to this topic) then I can use whatever I want to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is uniformly continuous, which by definition means that if the arguments are close to each other then the values are close to each other. In your case for two points $X=(x_1,x_2,y_1,y_2)$ and $X'=(x_1',x'_2,y_1',y_2')$ we have $$ d_2\,(f(X),f(X'))\le d_4\,(X,X')$$ where $d_n$ denotes for example the euclidean distance in $\mathbb{R}^n.$

Comment: Is this a variation of the '$\epsilon\delta$' definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes, with $\delta =\varepsilon.$

Comment: Okay, thank you. That was simpler than expected.

Comment: Could you maybe tell me if there is any reason to define the function as $f :\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ instead of simply $\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$? It seems to just add confusion, unless there is a reason?

Comment: @Logi Perhaps there is some interpretation behind it. For example $f$ is defined on pairs of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the result is a new vector.

Comment: Okay, thank you again for the help.